# What should I use for randfunc in RSA.generate() with PyCrypto 2.0.1?

Tags: python, pycrypto

I'm trying to generate RSA keys in versions 2.0.1 and 2.6.1 of PyCrypto.

When I specify a single argument to RSA.generate – the number of bits, e.g. 4096 – such as the code below, everything works fine in version 2.6.1:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
keys = RSA.generate(4096)
```

But when I run it with PyCrypto version 2.0.1, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: generate_c() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

I know that the new API has a `randfunc=None` and that is the reason why it works in 2.6.1.

My problem is that I do not know what is an acceptable `randfunc` in 2.0.1. What should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should use os.urandom.**

Quoting from the [PyCrypto documentation](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.PublicKey.RSA-module.html#generate):

> randfunc (callable) - Random number generation function; **it should accept a single integer N and return a string of random data N bytes long**. If not specified, a new one will be instantiated from Crypto.Random.

and then there’s an “Attention” section:

> You should always use a cryptographically secure random number generator, such as the one defined in the Crypto.Random module; don't just use the current time and the random module.

The Crypto.Random module isn’t present in PyCrypto 2.0.1, so you can’t use this approach here. Instead, you should use [`os.urandom()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.urandom). Quoting from the docs (emphasis mine):

> Return a string of n random bytes suitable for cryptographic use.
>
> This function returns random bytes from an OS-specific randomness source. **The returned data should be unpredictable enough for cryptographic applications, though its exact quality depends on the OS implementation.** On a UNIX-like system this will query /dev/urandom, and on Windows it will use CryptGenRandom(). If a randomness source is not found, NotImplementedError will be raised.

That sounds like an appropriate choice of randfunc to me.

Answer (score 0):

I know the thread is really old but i try the same thing in ElGamal with error:

```
'bytes' object is not callable
```

My line is: `key = ElGamal.generate(length, randfunc=os.urandom(10))`